# How to prevent a button to submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery/javascript so maybe I am taking a complete wrong path here.

I have a button within my form, and its job is just doing some DOM manipulation. Certainly not submitting the form.

```
<button id="add_deals_button" class="btn btn-success"></button>
```

In my js file I have written the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
  $("#add_deals_button").click(add_deals)
});
```

When I click the button, it does the DOM manipulation, but also it sends a POST, hence submits the form.  How do I prevent the button from submitting anything?

**UPDATE:**

```
function add_deals(e){
    $('#hidden_deals').clone().attr({'class':'none'}).appendTo('#deal_status tbody')

}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Raminson, I dont think this is a duplicate, as I am trying to prevent submitting altogether. Your suggested duplicate, doesn't do that. Please remove this before the question is closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to add this to the `button` tag:

```
type="button"
```

E.g.:

```
<button id="add_deals_button" type="button" class="btn btn-success"></button>
```

By default, the [`type` of `button` elements is `"submit"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-button-element.html#attr-button-type), which submits the form. But if the `type` is `"button"`, it's just a button, not a form-submission button.

Comment: This has worked. And its a clean solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Depending on this that you have bound to the click and what you want to achieve you could return false;

```
 $("#add_deals_button").click(function(e) {
      // do your actions
      add_deals();
      return false;
 });
```

This will, in jQuery do the same as

```
 $("#add_deals_button").click(function(e) {
      // do your actions
      e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();          
 });
```